# Plot different color for different categorical levels in ggplot

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have this dataframe composed of sample IDs, PCA values and respective population.
[my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcmwt.png)

I have generated the MDS plot for this data using ggplot in python using the following command:

```
from ggplot import *
print ggplot(aes(x='C1', y='C2'), data=mds)+ geom_point(alpha=0.6, colour='black', fill='red') + ggtitle('My plot')
```

and the plot looks like this:
[My MDS plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Msp.png)

I was wondering how I can assign different colors to each individual based on their population lable?

Comment: I don't use python a whole lot and when I do it's not for graphing but my experience with R's ggplot2 package would leave me to believe that you throw the population variable into the geom_point call under its aesthetics like in the following: ``...geom_point(aes(fill=Population), alpha=0.6, colour='black')...`` Just a shot in the dark. Also in R's ggplot2 geom_point calls in the default shape (like the one used in your plot) cannot accept fill commands so I think it should be color=Population.

Comment: Mer30 Cyrus, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
from ggplot import *

p = ggplot(aes(x='C1', y='C2', color='Population'), data=mds)+ geom_point(alpha=0.6) + ggtitle('My plot')

print p
```

Make sure to have the quotes around your column names and to have the `color` argument inside your `aes` function.